# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldpdk

Tags: linux, dpdk

I'm trying to link static dpdk with libpcap and whenever I run the command `make` it shows me this error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldpdk
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:419: libpcap.so] Error 1
```

how can I slove this please ?
note:
O.S: ubuntu 20.04.4
dpdk : 19.11

Comment: how did you install libdpdk?

Comment: @MalekChebli do you want to build and install DPDK from scratch or you are looking for Ubuntu distro package? Please explain

Comment: @VipinVarghese built DPDK already ad I enabled the shared library option and now I'm trying to compile libpcap with dpdk support with this following command ` ./configure --with-dpdk && make -s all && make -s testprogs && make install`

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I tied to follow the instructions on here http://wei48221.blogspot.com/2017/08/linux-how-to-solve-problem-of-usrbinld.html

Comment: @MalekChebli can you please share the configure or make file to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Is the libdpdk-dev package installed?

Comment: And from what version of the libpcap source are you trying to build?  The tcpdump.org 1.9.x doesn't support DPDK and the tcpdump.org 1.10.1 doesn't seem to have this problem.

Comment: And you say "I'm trying to link static dpdk with libpcap" - did you do anything special when running the configure script to do a static link?

Comment: @user16139739 the libdpdk-dev package is already installed and the libpcap source version I'm trying to build is 1.10.0-PRE-GIT

Comment: @user16139739 I addded some changes to the file pcap-dpdk.c cause the configure script wasn't able to identify eth_addr so I changed it to rte_eth_addr

Comment: "the libpcap source version I'm trying to build is 1.10.0-PRE-GIT"  1.10.0-PRE-GIT is an out-of-date and unsupported version; it's the tip of the main branch from before the release of libpcap 1.10.  Did you mean 1.10.1, which is the current release, or did you mean 1.11.1-PRE-GIT (1.11, *not* 1.10), which means "tip of the main branch of the libpcap repository"?

Comment: Or are you building from the 1.10 branch of the libpcap git repository?  If so, do a `git pull` to make sure your repository is up-to-date, and try it then.  If it doesn't work, file an issue at the GitHub issues list for libpcap, and attach the `config.log` file as well as the output of `configure` (and attach them as text files, *not* as light-gray-on-black screenshots).

Comment: What works now?  Building from the tip of the main branch of the libpcap repository (i.e., doing a `git pull` to get the latest version), building from the tip of the 1.10 branch (i.e., doing a `git pull` to get the latest version), or downloading the 1.10.1 source and building from that?

Comment: @user16139739 actually I used the ` cmake -DDPDK_DIR=$RTE_SDK/$RTE_TARGET ../  ` commande to build libpcap instead of `./configure --with-dpdk` and installed the missing dependencies

Comment: If this was after doing a `git pull`, does `./configure --with-dpdk` also work now?

Answer (score 0):

Libpcap's configure script now only uses pkg-config to try to find DPDK, so the configure script no longer attempts to guess with what libraries to link; this means that if there is no "libdpdk" library, just the libraries that DPDK provides (of which there are at least 48, and possibly over 100), DPDK's pkg-config file won't list a `-ldpdk` and the libpcap configure script and build process won't try to build with it.

That's in the tip of the main and 1.10 branches and, if there's a 1.10.2 release, will be in that release as well.